# MS Bot faster initial start

Tags: azure, cloud, botframework, bots

When I first send a message to my bot regardless of the channel it takes long for it to respond the first time. Afterwards it is fine. How to get rid of this "cold start?" delay? Will changing the plan in Azure help?

Comment: What kind of Plan do you have for your App Service ?

Comment: Free tier plan.

Comment: In that case it can be one of the reasons yes. To avoid this cold start, you could set your App Service to "Always On" (in its Application Settings), but you can't do this while being on the free plan

Comment: @NicolasR Can you provide us with where exactly this setting is? I think my service is always on.

Comment: @Bolde, See Fei Han answer with the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, web apps (the bot application is hosted as Azure web app) are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time.

As Nicolas R mentioned in his comment, you could enable "**Always On**" for your bot application to keep the app loaded all the time. You can turn on it on your bot service’s **Application Settings** blade, which will need you to [scale up your app service plan tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-scale#scale-up-your-pricing-tier).

[image]

Comment: hi @Fei Han , I did exactly as you described and updated my plan. Still, the bot's answer after opening telegram and texting is very slow, compared to other telegram bots. Is there another factor that could be slowing it down? The bot does not perform intensive computations or api calls, and at the beginning it is just sending a greeting message.

Comment: Do your other bot app(s) use same service plan, within same region?